# npm install -g @angular/cli is stucking resolveWithNewModule punycode@2.1.1 checking installable status

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

i tried in command prompt like,
npm install -g @angular/cli
I am getting stuck in resolveWithNewModule punycode@2.1.1 checking installable status

Comment: Which OS are you using ?

Comment: I am using windows @SanyamGoel

Comment: First thing do --> npm uninstall -g angular-cli 
Second open cmd as Administrator and try the installation command again

Comment: I tried @SanyamGoel , But not working . Still stuck in punycode@2.1.1

Comment: Try with version 6 like this once

npm install -g @angular/cli@6.1.1

Comment: npm install -g @angular/cli@latest is the command for the latest version that should also work

Comment: still not working... Stucking in the same point. @SanyamGoel

Comment: whcih node version are you using ?

Comment: Try removing package-lock.json, then running `npm i` again.

Comment: using v10.15.0 @SanyamGoel

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue but After trying lots of times, it finally resolved by itself. finally, the installation of Angular completed successfully.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest --verbose
```

Comment: Which version of node you are using?

Comment: v10.15.0 @Sneha Pawar

Comment: @SnehaPawar I have used same command as above. Its stucked in fetchmetadata:http get 200 http://registry.npm.js

Comment: @SnehaPawar, Please answer on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54989329/npm-install-angular-cli-stuck

Comment: @user6044627 please check your internet connection. maybe this is internet connection issue