# NPM install angular cli stuck

Tags: angular, npm

I am trying to install angular/cli for angular 7.

- NPM Version: 6.7.0
- Node Version: v11.10.1

When I execute command **npm install -g @angular/cli**

Installation gets stuck during execution . Please see screen shot 
[image]

Comment: Is Punycode package in your package.json file?

Comment: @SnehaPawar I try to install globally

Comment: Have you tried to install a specific version of CLI?

Comment: Yes, I have always stucked on same . I have also uninstall and change nodejs version also, but success.

Comment: Try to install locally first and let me know what is the output  => npm i @angular/cli@1.7.4

Comment: I am working on local server . please share your email id or number I will share my screen. I have spend lot of time to findout its solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189431/discussion-between-sneha-pawar-and-sudhir).

Comment: lets discuss on chat

Comment: @SnehaPawar After executing npm i and repeat installation it will stuck on other steps fetmetadata 304 http://registry.npm.js

Comment: try performing the installation using windows powershell

Answer (score 0):

First clear the cashe using following command.

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Then try

```
npm install -g @angular/core
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: npm install -g @angular/core return 2 waring and 2nd command again stucked

Comment: After last command it stucked on other steps fetmetadata 304 registry.npm.js